# Is Visual Studio Code able to have multiple includePath for different OS in .vscode/c_cpp_properties.json?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working on my project on multiple operating systems, including Windows, WSL Ubuntu and Mac, using VSC. My includePath in `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` is based on the settings in my Mac. However, when I work on other OS's, header files in such OS's have different locations from Mac.

Is there any way to solve this problem, excluding using other IDE's?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a platform-dependent configuration by adding `"name": <your_platform>` to your `c_cpp_properties.json` file, like this:

```json
"configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Mac",
      "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
      "includePath": ["${myDefaultIncludePath}", "/another/path"],
      ...
    }
  ],
```

In principle, you can use any `name` that identifies your configuration, but `Linux`, `Mac`, and `Win32` are special identifiers for configurations that will be automatically selected on those platforms (see: [official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference#_configuration-properties)).